# Attack on a string created by a developer

Tags: xss, sql-injection, programming, code-execution, string

Go and Java have "compile time constants", and JavaScript will soon get a feature that allows "Distinguishing strings from a trusted developer from strings that may be attacker controlled" via [isTemplateObject](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-is-template-object).

These allow the program to check if a variable contains a string that came from the source code (i.e. a literal).

This is useful, as it allows you to be sure a variable cannot cause an Injection Vulnerability.

For example an SQL string, where the user values have been kept separate (parameterised queries).

In theory, combining literals should be fine (think of a programmer building up an SQL/HTML/CLI string).

But, if the attacker was given the ability to extract an arbitrary part of the string, or some way of using `split()` to convert the string into an array... is there any way this could cause issues, and undermine this valuable distinction of "strings from a trusted developer".

---

For example:

```
$my_literal_html = '<a href="?">Example<a>';
```

This by itself cannot contain an injection vulnerability (does not contain user data).

We could even append more HTML to it, and it will also be fine:

```
$my_literal_html .= ' <em>Text</em>';
```

At this point we would send it to a HTML Templating Engine, which could check that it's a literal... then it's free to incorporate the user supplied values (using the appropriate encoding, and context checking, like preventing 'javascript:' URLs).

But, is there anything the programmer could do, which could inadvertently break this... to take their literal, split/cut/substr it, still be seen as a literal, but also introduce a security issue.

Maybe `$‍length` could be attacker controlled (for some reason)?

```
$‍start = 0;
$‍length = ($_GET['length'] ?? 9);

$my_literal_html = substr($my_literal_html, $‍start, $‍length);
```

That would result in the string '<a href="'... which I think is still fine, but in a larger program, could issues be introduced?

---

For reference, I'm writing the [is_literal RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/is_literal) for PHP, it will allow libraries to check certain input strings came from the programmer, and it does support concatenated strings... but a question has come up about splitting strings, I don't think it's useful (can't think of why anyone would), but I'm also concerned it could undermine the security value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126169/discussion-on-question-by-craig-francis-attack-on-a-string-created-by-a-develope).